# Print out all functions in Mathematica

Tags: functions

Sometimes I only remember parts of a function name and I want find that function name quickly, and if I search in the document center, it will give too much informations related to that and difficult to find what I'm looking for. So is there a way to print out all the MMA functions in alphabetical order in a notebook, so that I can search only in the function names? Thanks.

Comment: Names["System`*"] might be what you are after.

Comment: Related: `Names["*KnownPart*"]` adding the appropriate contexts as needed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is `` Documentation`HelpLookup["guide/AlphabeticalListing"] ``

If you want to tweak it yourself, you can start with

```
SetAttributes[makeSearchable, Listable];
(* Thanks @rm-rf *)
makeSearchable[s_String] := Hyperlink[s, "paclet:ref/" <> s]

firstLetter = StringTake[#, 1] &;

CreatePalette[
 OpenerView@{firstLetter@First@#, Column@makeSearchable@#} & /@ 
   SplitBy[
    Pick[#, StringMatchQ[#, WordCharacter ..]] &@Names["System`*"], 
    firstLetter] // Column, WindowTitle -> "Function list", 
     WindowElements -> {"VerticalScrollBar"}]
```

However, the practical approach is, as suggested, to use `Names` with the "*" character for unknown parts, or better still, `Information`, as in  `?Pl*` (or the autocompletion functionality)

Comment: You can also do this without the `HelpLookup` function. Simply replace `Column@makeSearchable@#` with `Column[Hyperlink[#, "paclet:ref/" <> #] & /@ #]`. I like this because clicking a different links does not launch a new doc window (default doc center behaviour) and you can always open a new window with rt.click

Comment: @rm-rf that's worth editing in, thanks!